rounding to nearst 0 or 5 in n (add_n()) gtsummary outputbale
I need help in rounding the last digit to 0 or 5 in n column from add_n() in my gtsummary output table. any help is much appreciated
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)


round_05 <- function(x) {
  ceiling(x/5) * 5
} 


df %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = hba1c,
    include = -id,
    digits=list(everything() ~ c(round_05, 0))
    # digits=list(everything() ~ c(round_05, round_pct))
  ) %>% 
  add_p(pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)) %>%
  add_overall() %>%
  add_n()

here is my data
structure(list(id = 1:100, age = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", 
"b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", 
"a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c"), sex = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F"), country = c("eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", 
"wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", 
"wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", 
"eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", 
"eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", 
"scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", 
"scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", 
"scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", 
"wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", 
"wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", 
"eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", 
"eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", 
"scot"), edu = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", 
"x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", 
"y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", 
"x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", 
"y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z"
), hba1c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))


Because the statistic argument for gtsummary::add_n() uses glue::glue() syntax you can run arbitrary code.
Note, the available statistics such as n will be character so you must convert to numeric to perform calculations.
library(gtsummary)

trial[c("trt", "age", "grade", "response")] %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt) %>%
  add_n(statistic = "{round(as.integer(n) / 5) * 5}")


Reprex files hosted with  on GitHub

thanks  my hba1c is factor variable which has 2 categories so when i run this code  add_n(statistic = "{round(as.integer(n) / 5) * 5}") i get NAs in my n column

I am not sure why you would be getting NAs. hba1c does not appear to be a factor in your example data (see my other answer to see this trick applied to your example data), and even if I convert hba1c to factor with df$hba1c<- factor(df$hba1c), I do not end up with NAs. I suspect something else is happening.

thanks yes there is something else happening in the real data. let me try to find it out thanks for your help

Here are some additional examples of formatting table statistics including the add_n(statistic = "{round(as.integer(n) / 5) * 5}") example run on your example data.
library(gtsummary)

# function to generate style-functions
style_round_any <- function(accuracy, is_p = FALSE) {
  function(x) {
    if(is_p)
      x <- 100 * x
    
    ceiling(x / accuracy) * accuracy
  }
}

# generate function to style n
style_n <- style_round_any(5)

# generate function to style p
style_p <- style_round_any(2, is_p = TRUE)

# vector of styling functions for n and p
style_n_p <- c(style_n, style_p)

df <- structure(list(id = 1:100, age = c("a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", 
"c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", 
"b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", 
"b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
"c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", 
"a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", 
"b", "b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", 
"c", "c", "c"), sex = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", 
"M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", 
"F"), country = c("eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", 
"wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", 
"wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", 
"eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", 
"eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", 
"scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", 
"scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", 
"scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", 
"wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", 
"wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", "eng", "eng", 
"eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", "scot", "eng", 
"eng", "eng", "eng", "wale", "wale", "wale", "scot", "scot", 
"scot"), edu = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", 
"z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", 
"x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", 
"y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", 
"z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", 
"x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", 
"y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", 
"z", "z", "z", "x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z", "z"
), hba1c = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))

df %>% 
  tbl_summary(
    by = hba1c,
    include = -id,
    digits = 
      list(
        # Example 1
        # - no specification for age
        # - allow tbl_summary to guess an appropriate number of decimals to round n and p
        #   - n will be rounded to 0 decimal places
        #   - p will be rounded to 0 decimal places
        # Example 2
        # - supply a vector of decimal places for n and p
        #   - n will be rounded to 1 decimal place
        #   - p will be rounded to 2 decimal places
        sex ~ c(1, 2),
        # Example 3
        # - user may also pass styling functions
        # - Example 3A
        #   - pass a vector of styling functions for n and p respectively
        #     - n will be rounded to the nearest 8
        #     - p will be rounded to the nearest 10
        country ~ c(style_round_any(8), style_round_any(10, is_p = TRUE)),
        # - Example 3B
        #   - pass a vector of styling functions for n and p respectively
        #     - n will be rounded to the nearest 5
        #     - p will be rounded to the nearst 2
        edu ~ c(style_n, style_p)
      )
  ) %>% 
  add_p(pvalue_fun = ~ style_pvalue(.x, digits = 2)) %>%
  add_overall(
    digits = list(
      # Example 4
      # - use all_categorical() to override all digits specficiations in tbl_summary()
      #   - all n will be rounded to the nearest 5 in overall column for all variables
      #   - all p will be rounded to the nearest 2 in overall column for all variables
      all_categorical() ~ style_n_p
    )
  ) %>%
  add_n(
    # Example 5
    # - a way to round the last digit to 0 or 5 in n column from add_n()
    statistic = "{round(as.integer(n) / 5) * 5}"
  )


Reprex files hosted with  on GitHub
